# How to get data from coredata in which firstname starting from number?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have used core data to store data, now I have an issue that how to
get those records which was beingwith any number character or first
character is number, so need to those entire records which was
starting character is number, how can I do this ? any idea ?

Comment: Create a predicate with a block, and pass that to your `NSFetchRequest`

Comment: not getting it.!! how can I do this ?

Comment: Which part? You can read about `NSPredicate` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html). Do a test inside the block to see if the string starts with a number an return true in the block if it does.

Comment: yes, predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", str]; but using this I have get only specific number records not not entire..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution like below.

```
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@) OR (firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@) OR (firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@) OR (firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@) OR (firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@) OR (firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@) OR (firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@) OR (firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@) OR (firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@) OR (firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@)" argumentArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"0",nil]];
```

This was working perfect :).

Comment: Refer my answer for a better way of implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do MATCHES in your predicate and then use a regular expression.

`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"jobStatus MATCHES %@",your_regex];`

Answer (score 0):

This is a much cleaner way to implement this, using regular expressions.

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName matches '^[0-9].*'"];
```